# How to make Suspend and Hibernate work on MacBookPro 5,4?

Tags: macbook-pro

A several months ago I got a MacBokPro and was glad to find out a [clear documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro5-4/Lucid) for installing Ubuntu on it.

Installing ubuntu was easy, but the Suspend and Hibernate options are not working and I can find a solution for it.
It is a real problem for me as the Sleep/Suspend functionality is a feature I use many times along the day.

I tried [this](http://techieblurbs.blogspot.de/2012/05/suspend-freeze-on-macbookpro-82-and.html) (editing `/usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults`) but still after suspending and waking up the screen is just a black and white lines. The only thing I can do to solve the problem is to restart the X-Server.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you install Lucid like in the documentation, or precise or quantal?

Comment: Do you mean your computer doesn't turn on or off successfully after hibernation? Or you don't see a hibernation button(its disabled by default)?

Comment: Er I think it is the first one, since suspend doesn't work too in his case

Comment: exactly like in the docs.

Comment: I don't see hibernate at all. weird thing: no I there is no problem with suspend... what??

Answer (score 1):

After changing the graphical driver seems like the suspend functionality is working great.

just go to "Additional Drivers" then changed to the recommended driver and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Latest linux kernel fixs the problem,
install with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```